# running fuerte packages on electric

Tags: ros-fuerte, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have not yet made the conversion to fuerte (still using electric) but I wanted to use the Gazebo 1.0 package that was released in fuerte.  Is there a way of doing this or is there another easy method of running Gazebo 1.0 on electric?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35159/running-fuerte-packages-on-electric/) by [kpayson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2485/kpayson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-05-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is certainly no easy way.

You can check out the Fuerte version of the Gazebo sources and try to backport it to Electric. Anticipate many build and integration problems.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kpayson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2485/kpayson/) on 2012-05-31**:
Thanks for the quick reply.  That describes the experience I had been having attempting this, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing out on some hidden ros feature, I think my best bet is just to upgrade to Fuerte.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-31**:
Yes. Getting gazebo 1.0 to build and run on Electric is hard enough. Then, you'd likely find other packages in Electric that require the older gazebo version.